# The result of mann-whitney u test in Jupyter notebook couldn't be reproduced

Tags: python, jupyter

The result of mann-whitney u test in Jupyter notebook couldn't be reproduced.

First, we did mann-whitney u test for test dataset.
[image]

Second, we did mann-whitney u test for my dataset. I have to apologize that my dataset cannot be attached because that is very big and confidential data.
[image]

Then, we did mann-whitney u test for test dataset again and got the error messege.
[image]

Did you know this phenomenon?
What can be the reason for this phenomenon?

MacOS 10.14.5
python 3.7.2
jupyter notebook 4.4.0

```
import numpy as np
from scipy

np.random.seed(12345678)  #fix random seed to get the same result
n1 = 200  # size of first sample
n2 = 300  # size of second sample
rvs1 = stats.norm.rvs(size=n1, loc=0., scale=1)
rvs2 = stats.norm.rvs(size=n2, loc=0.5, scale=1.5)
print(stats.mannwhitneyu(rvs1, rvs2))
print(type(rvs1))
print(len(rvs1))
print(len(rvs2))
print(stats.ks_2samp(rvs1, rvs2))

alive= np.loadtxt('alive.csv', delimiter=',', dtype='int64')
expired= np.loadtxt('expired.csv', delimiter=',', dtype='int64')

print(stats.mannwhitneyu(alive, expired))
print("p-value")
print(np.round(stats.mannwhitneyu(alive, expired).pvalue, decimals=4))
print("statistics")
print(len(alive))
len_alive = len(alive)
print(len(expired))
len_expired = len(expired)
stats = stats.mannwhitneyu(alive, expired).statistic
ps = stats/(len_alive * len_expired)
print(ps)
```

Comment: Please share code/data as text in the post itself, not as images. If you can't share data in order for this error to be reproduced, then there's not much we can do. See: [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your critical comment. First of all, I shared the code.

Comment: This should be closed, since the issue was just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a phenomenon, you named something in your input 15 `stats`. When you are calling `stats.norm` in your input 16 it is trying to run `stats.norm.rvs` on the object you created in input 15, you are not calling the scipy.stats module. This is why it is so important not to name your objects the same as the name of python functions or methods.

Comment: That was my simple mistake. Thank you so much.

Comment: Easy to overlook things like this when doing a lot of programming. One easy way (although not super practical for real programs) is to add a number to the end of each object you create, so like `stats1 = stats.manwhitteyu()` in this case.